# Plot return me a blank windows

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the compression ratio  but the plot return me a blank windows , It's earlier working fine, but now I don't know what is the problem here is my code

```
function goodCompressionLevel = findGoodCompressionLevel(targetRatio, filename)
       width = 672;
        height = 380;


for compressionLevel = 1:255 
    [~,~,ext] = fileparts(filename);
    if strcmp(ext, '.db') ~= 1
        originalFileSize = 8*width*height;
        [~,name,~] = fileparts(filename);

            output = strcat(name, '_temp.jxr');
            system(['/usr/local/Cellar/jxrlib/1.1/bin/JxrEncApp  -i ' filename ' -o ' output ' -q ' num2str(compressionLevel)]);

            fileInfo = dir(output);
            newFileSize = fileInfo.bytes;

            ratios(compressionLevel+1) = originalFileSize/newFileSize;
            fprintf('Current Ratio: %d\n', ratios(compressionLevel+1));
            %delete(output);

    end
end

 plot(ratios);

minDist = Inf;
for r = 1:length(ratios)
    display(abs((ratios(r) - targetRatio)));
    display(minDist);
    if abs((ratios(r) - targetRatio)) <= minDist
        minDist = abs((ratios(r) - targetRatio));
    else
        goodCompressionLevel = r-1;
        display(goodCompressionLevel);
        break;

    end

end

end
```

Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Examine the contents of `ratio` without plotting it.  Is it empty?  Is it full of NaNs?

Answer (score 0):

Check maybe if the 'ratios' contains 'NaN' values. your original file size is a very large number and I am unsure what fileInfo.bytes returns. 
if you want to visualize the plot more conveniently try

```
 plot(ratios,'.')
```

this is will dot all the existing points on the plot.